# javascript Array.splice() does nothing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code in my update function, which is called 30 times per second:

```
        // Checking collision between rune and the players:
        for(var j = 0; j < this.players.length; j++) {
          if(this.checkCollision(this.players[j], this.runes[i])) {
            this.runes[i].activate(this.players[j]);
            this.runes[i].isHidden = true;
            this.runes[i].onDeactivate = function() {
              console.log(i);
              self.runes.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
        }
```

before that I have:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.runes.length; i++) ...
```

the self.runes.splice(i, 1) does nothing to an array... i is being set to some value. I just want to remove the not active rune from array of runes. Any Ideas?

Comment: by the way, onDeactivate is being called, i've tested that...

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity (I know exactly what's going on) but what does `console.log(i)` show you?

Comment: it depends on which rune I take with player... for example now it's showing 507... I wonder if self isn't a problem

Comment: You're calling `self.runes.splice(i, 1)` in an asynchronous function. By the time it runs, `i` will be outside the length of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

Firstly, at the time of calling `onDeactivate`, `i` will have reached `this.runes.length` and this is what you will be seeing in the `console.log(i)` call. The classic fix to resolve that issue is something like:

```
(function(i) {
    // code that relies on i
})(i);
```

This will essentially "lock" the value of `i` for the contents of that closure.

The second problem is that `splice` modifies the array, and you're not accommodating for that. Let's say you have three runes:

```
[rune_0, rune_1, rune_2]
```

Now say `rune_1` gets deactivated, so the code `splice(1,1)` is called to remove it. Now your array looks like:

```
[rune_0, rune_2]
```

Now `rune_2` is deactivated, so `splice(2,1)` is called. That removes the `[2]` element from the array... but there isn't one any more.

```
[rune_0, rune_2]
```

The rune is still there.

To remove a rune from the array, you can do something like:

```
this.runes = this.runes.filter(function(rune) {return rune !== toremove;});
```

Where `toremove` is the rune you want gone.